# K tells the archivist is something like, You must have been adorable -- significance?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

When K is visiting the vast record archive (IIRC it is a Wallace facility) the archivist says something about his childhood and K says to this man, certainly not a conventionally handsome person, "You must have been adorable." (Or something to that effect.)

This sounds like a subtle dig, but is it? Would a Replicant say this to a human, make a joke at his expense? K shows himself even in conversation with the other Replicants to be sort of lowkey and unaggressive.

Could what K says to this human be actually an attempt to compliment the human, sort of a default behavior or is K actually intentionally being sarcastic?

Maybe the fact that K is commenting on a human's childhood, something K never had (but we know how central this will become) makes this more than a random comment about the bald guy's appearance. In fact, I am pretty sure this is why the amazing director/writer included this dialog which otherwise might simply help define K's character and his interactions with humans.

In the same way that Replicants are not supposed to kill humans (or at least one might think that would be part of their personality) they might be deferential to them. But K is not only not deferential -- perhaps shy and he certainly treats his owner with great respect -- he will readily kill humans if needed and maybe this line foreshadows this.

Comment: I don't think this is an especially subtle dig. K's default setting seems to be 'broody sarcastic'

Comment: @Valorum: Perhaps he is just being sort of sarcastic. But it  just occurred to me that a Replicant reflecting upon what a human looked like in a childhood that K never had (but we know what then happens) is perhaps why that was thrown in. Do you agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a joke. He says that his mother doted on him as a baby and K can't resist making a snarky comment after having had to endure the (weird-looking) clerk rambling on about his childhood.

> **FILE CLERK:** *Funny how only paper lasts. We had everything on drives. My mom still cries over the lost baby pictures.*
>
> **K:** *Shame. You must’ve been adorable.*
>
> [Clerk misses the joke. Surprised to find something]
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner 2049: Screenplay](https://www.scriptslug.com/script/blade-runner-2049-2017)</sup></sub>

Comment: I am not a believer when the director has complete control of what we see and hear in random jokes. Again, when you have not had your own childhood, any comments about childhood are likely to have an affect on you. Indeed, K may be hurt by any mention of childhood even innocent ones.

Comment: @releseabe - I don't think so. It's just a laconic dig.

Comment: I remain unconvinced. I sure would like to know what Denis might say but I doubt whether I will ever manage to speak with him.